# Kendo grid with nested object

Tags: c#, kendo-ui

I've got viewmodel with some parameter and another VM in it.

ViewModel:

```cs
public class TestListViewModel
{
    public string Param { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TestViewModel> Counts { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I'm grouping data by Param and I want to show all data on Kendo Grid like this:
[image]

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name('kendoGrid').
    .Columns(columns => {
        <!-- how can I do it here? -->
        
    }
)
```

Comment: Do you have to use a Grid or can you use a TreeList ? https://www.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treelist

Comment: Prefer Grid, but also looked at TreeList :-) anyway I hope there is a simple solution to do it with a Grid

Comment: Here is an exemple on Telerik docs: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/aggregates

Comment: @ArwynFr but model there is binding in .DataSource(...), and aggregate data from model with pure(?) data - I mean no nested class inside. I've got grouped data and bind it with Grid here @(Html.Kendo().-->Grid(Model)<--...). I don't know how to use this example from telerik, when I have class in my mode

Comment: If you want to use a grid, you'll need to flatten your viewmodels to a collection of (param, name, count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to flatten your data for Grid to work:

**Models.TestViewModel.cs**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string Param { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

**Controllers.TestController.cs**

```
public class TestController
{
    public IActionResult Aggregates()
    {
        IEnumerable<TestViewModel> Models = // FIXME populate your data here
        return View(Models);
    }
}
```

**Views.Test.Aggregates.cshtml**

```
@Model IEnumerable<TestViewModel> // this view displays a collection of flatten models

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name('kendoGrid')
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(model => model.Name);
        columns.Bound(model => model.Count);
        columns.Bound(model => model.Param)
            .GroupHeaderTemplate(@<text>@item.Title</text>); // this is displayed on top of each group
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Server()
        .Group(groups => groups.Add(model => model.Param)) // tells Grid to group by Param
        .Read(read => read.Action("Aggregates", "Test"))
    )
)
```